# how to test a method of a component in enzyme is it calls a method which is passed as prop

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

```
handleConfirm = () => {
    this.props.handleCompletionDateChange();
    this.setState({ showInformation: false });
  };
```

I have above method handleConfirm in our class component DateSection
if I test handleConfirm method using below code I am getting error as

```
 TypeError: _this.props.handleCompletionDateChange is not a function
```

```
const wrapper1 = shallow(<DateSection {...props} />);

    const instance = wrapper1.instance() as any;

    spyOn(instance, 'handleConfirm').and.callThrough();

    expect(instance.handleConfirm()).toBe(true);
    expect(instance.handleConfirm).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

How should pass the above function as a prop while testing,

Comment: can you make a simple code on codesandbox ?

Answer (score 0):

You better not access `instance()` in tests. Tests become fragile(say, converting component into functional will break everything while component itself can be fine) and less reliable(if you calling methods that will never be called in real life - e.g. if that method is not called by others and not bound as event handler).\

Instead you need to find way to call that with the help of `.simulate()` or `.props().someCabllackProp(...)`.

Assuming this `handleConfirm` is `onClick` handled for some `<button name="confirm">`:

```
it('calls handleCompletionDateChange', () => {
  const handleCompletionDateChange = jest.fn();
  const wrapper1 = shallow(<DateSection 
    {...props} 
    handleCompletionDateChange={handleCompletionDateChange} \
  />);
  wrapper1.find("button[name='confirm']").simulate('click');
  expect(handleCompletionDateChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

The same to validate `this.setState({ showInformation: false });` part. We need to figure out how to validate that based on `render` results.
Something like

```
expect(wrapper1.find("[data-id='information-block']")).toHaveLength(0);
```